# Angular2 latest modules

Tags: angular, npm

I just started a new Sails + Angular2 project, and I pretty much wrapped the modules configuration (in the package.jso file) the those I saw in a tutorial.

But they were different then those I found in the latest tutorial by Google (the heros tutorial). When I put the deps from the tutorial, I got some errors with npm install (which I should solve myself, it is not the issue of the question).

There's always this delta, and I can't track the latest and the most "up to date" modules. I tried to look into the documentation, and if it's there- I probably missed it.

Is there any source of date which states the latest and tested (not RC) version of the basic modules (angular/common, angular/compiler, angular/core, angular/forms, angular/http, angular/platform-browser, angular/platform-browser-dynamic, angular/router, angular/upgrade)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the github page:

https://github.com/angular/angular

At the time of writing, the latest version is `2.3.0`.

You can also check https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/ and it will say the same (most of the time).

For the `@angular/router` package they use a slightly different version, because they rewrote the entire package halfway through. So when the version is `2.3.0` of the other modules, the router is at `3.3.0`

```
"@angular/common": "2.3.0",
"@angular/compiler": "2.3.0",
"@angular/core": "2.3.0",
"@angular/forms": "2.3.0",
"@angular/http": "2.3.0",
"@angular/platform-browser": "2.3.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.3.0",
"@angular/router": "3.3.0"
```